# Send email from iOS app using SendGrid

Tags: image, ios7, afnetworking, email-attachments, sendgrid

I am trying to to use mail api from [sendgrid.com](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html) but everytime it finishes with failure block.
Also I don't understand how to send the image as an attachment in the email. Can anybody tell me whats wrong in below code & how can  I send image ? I am using below code for now

```
-(void)sendEmail
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [params setValue:@"username" forKey:@"api_user"];
    [params setValue:@"sdsfddf23423" forKey:@"api_key"];
    [params setValue:@"test@gmail.com" forKey:@"to"];
    [params setValue:@"test user" forKey:@"toname"];
    [params setValue:@"Test SendGrid" forKey:@"subject"];
    [params setValue:@"Test SendGrid from iOS app" forKey:@"text"];
    [params setValue:@"noreply@gmail.com" forKey:@"from"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sendgrid.com/api"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:POST path:@"/mail.send.json"  parameters:params];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
        DLog(@"Get latest product info response : %@", response);
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Update

I made some changes in code & now I can send the email successfully as below

```
-(void)sendEmailWithoutImage
{

     NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"api_user": @"username",
                                 @"api_key": @"sdsfddf23423",
                                 @"subject":@"Test SendGrid",
                                 @"from":@"noreply@gmail.com",
                                 @"to":@"test@gmail.com",
                                 @"text":@"Test SendGrid from iOS app"};

    [[MyAPIClient sharedAPIClient] POST:@"mail.send.json" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"Success::responseObject : %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error::Mail response : %@", error);
    }];
}
```

But when I try to send the image as attachment then it result in 400 bad request. So I think there is some error in my file uploading block. Here is my code

```
-(void)sendEmailWithImage
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"api_user": @"username",
                                 @"api_key": @"sdsfddf23423",
                                 @"subject":@"Test SendGrid",
                                 @"from":@"noreply@gmail.com",
                                 @"to":@"test@gmail.com",
                                 @"text":@"Test SendGrid from iOS app"};

    [[MyAPIClient sharedAPIClient] POST:@"mail.send.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redWine.png"];
        NSData *imageToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload name:@"files" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"abc.png"] mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"Success::responseObject : %@", responseObject);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error::Mail response : %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Can you anybody tell me whats going wrong while uploading the image ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modified your code a little. It looks like there was an issue with the parameters being sent and the URL path.

Also since you are already using AFNetworking to make your POST request, you can follow their docs and example on how to send a photo over here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.1/

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"api_user": @"username",
                                 @"api_key": @"sdsfddf23423",
                                 @"Test SendGrid":@"test",
                                 @"from":@"noreply@gmail.com",
                                 @"to":@"test@gmail.com",
                                 @"text":@"Test SendGrid from iOS app"};


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sendgrid.com/api/"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"mail.send.json"  parameters:parameters];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
        // DLog(@"Get latest product info response : %@", response);
         NSLog(@"Success: %@", response);
     } failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"%@",error);
     }];
    [operation start];
```

**Update****

Created a [Sendgrid-ios library](https://github.com/kunal732/sendgrid-ios) to make it easier to send an email and photo attachment.

```
//create Email Object
gridmail *msg = [gridmail user:@"username" andPass:@"password"];

//set parameters
msg.to = @"foo@bar.com";
msg.subject = @"subject goes here";
msg.from = @"me@bar.com";
msg.text = @"hello world";   
msg.html = @"<h1>hello world!</h1>";


//Image attachment
[msg attachImage:self.photo];

//Send email through Web API Transport
[msg sendWithWeb];
```

Comment: Thanks for link. I am not aware of AFNetworking v2.0 . Actually my account is not provisioned by SendGrid thats why I am not able to send email.

Comment: Happy to provision your account for you

Comment: Please see my update. Now I am able to send the email but there is some issue if I add image as attachment. Can you tell me whats going wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for library. Thanks for the new library... I really appreciate your help. In my code only problem is `files`. Changing it to `files[abc.png]` fixed my issue.

Comment: Can I remove the `If you'd like to unsubscribe and stop receiving these emails click here` line from the body of the email sent using SendGrid ? If not, what happens if user clicks on unsubscribe ? I want my user to receive those email as it contains order information & payment info . Thanks

Comment: Kunal- Since the SendGrid library is no longer recommended for use, I am utilizing the sendGrid PHP script on my web server to send mail from the iPhone. Works just fine. However, I'm having difficulty attaching a photo from in iOS and sending it as an attachment. Do you have a recommendation/ code for this?